# Encountering errors when "lein new" is executed (on windows)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Other commands such as *lein repl* and *lein deps* etc work fine.

The output is as follows

C:\Users\test>lein version

Leiningen 2.0.0-preview3 on Java 1.7.0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

C:\Users\test>lein new first

Generating a project called first based on the 'default' template.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory f
ound for class: nil
        at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:495)
        at clojure.java.io$fn_*7795$G*_7790__7802.invoke(io.clj:63)
        at clojure.java.io$reader.doInvoke(io.clj:96)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at leiningen.new.templates$slurp_resource.invoke(templates.clj:29)
        at leiningen.new.templates$renderer$fn__713.doInvoke(templates.clj:79)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
        at leiningen.new.default$default.invoke(default.clj:15)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at leiningen.new$create.doInvoke(new.clj:54)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at leiningen.new$create.invoke(new.clj:47)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:600)
        at leiningen.new$new.doInvoke(new.clj:101)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__699.doInvoke(main.clj:66)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:88)
        at leiningen.core.main$*main$fn*_731.invoke(main.clj:140)
        at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:140)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:600)
        at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:323)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:413)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

Comment: Try the Leiningen mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/leiningen

Comment: Please report this at https://github.com/Raynes/lein-newnew/issues

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and solved it by switching to lein 1.7.1.

Try downloading https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein.bat, and running:

```
lein self-install
```